# Uniqueness of spheres in prime decomposition of a 3-manifold

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed connected orientable 3-manifold.  Then Kneser tells us that there is a decomposition $M = P_1 \sharp \cdots \sharp P_k$ of $M$ into prime manifolds.  Milnor tells us that if $M = Q_1 \sharp \cdots \sharp Q_l$ then $k = l$ and the $Q_i$ are homeomorphic to the $P_j$ in some order.

Is there any theorem that tells us to what extent the spheres that give a prime decomposition are unique?  They are not unique up to isotopy at all bit I was wondering if there was some set of moves for getting between any set of prime decomposing spheres.

Comment: I think it would be hard to find better moves than what you get by following along with the proof of the uniqueness of the decomposition - i.e. whenever the proof replaces one sphere with another, that is an allowable move.

Answer (score 1):

Different sets of decomposing spheres are related by moves called **slide homeomorphisms**.

[Aschenbrenner et al. (2015)](https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/3-manifold-groups-final-version-031115) provide several references to this statement, see the remark after Theorem 1.2.1 on [page 9](https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/3-manifold-groups-final-version-031115#page=13). Among those, I've found the exposition in McCullough's 1986 paper [*Mappings of reducible 3-manifolds*](https://eudml.org/doc/267610) the most instructive, where the following is proven:

> **Theorem.** Let $M$ be a compact, connected, orientable 3-manifold. Then any orientation-preserving homeomorphism of $M$ is isotopic to a composition of the following four types of homeomorphisms:
>
> 1. homeomorphisms preserving summands,
> 2. interchanges of homeomorphic summands,
> 3. spins of $S^1\times S^2$ summands, and
> 4. slide homeomorphisms.

See pp. 68–69 of [[McCullough (1986)]](https://eudml.org/doc/267610) for details regarding these four homeomorphism types, and Section 2.2 in [[Zhao (2004)]](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(03)00218-9) for a visually aided description of slide homeomorphisms, the ones that are particularly relevant in view of your question.